# print preview using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

here i am having **working code for printing and print preview**,but its not working in **Mozilla.** plz let me know that how i make it to work in mozilla also..i want the print **preview as same like the irctc website is having**.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Print Preview</title>
<style type="text/css">
 @media print {
.noPrint {
    display:none;
  }
}
</style>
<script>
function printpr()
{
var OLECMDID = 7;
/* OLECMDID values:
* 6 – print
* 7 – print preview
* 1 – open window
* 4 – Save As
*/

var PROMPT = 1; // 2 DONTPROMPTUSER
var WebBrowser = '<OBJECT ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', WebBrowser);

WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID, PROMPT);
WebBrowser1.outerHTML = "";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
<asp:radiobutton ID="Radiobutton1" class="noPrint" runat="server"></asp:radiobutton>
<asp:textbox ID="Textbox1" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
<asp:checkboxlist ID="Checkboxlist1" class="noPrint" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>gsdghsg</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ggsgh</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="gdfgg">gfghghgf</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:checkboxlist>
<div class="noPrint"><asp:textbox ID="Textbox2" runat="server"></asp:textbox></asp:checkboxlist></div>
<input type='button'class="noPrint" value="Print Preview" onclick="printpr();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mozilla since recently items with some id are not automatically exposed into global namespace (window object).

You need to define a variable:

```
var PROMPT = 1; // 2 DONTPROMPTUSER
var WebBrowser = '<OBJECT ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', WebBrowser);

var WebBrowser1 = document.getElementById('WebBrowser1');

WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID, PROMPT);
WebBrowser1.outerHTML = "";
```

Comment: k. actly the above code is wrking in IE7..cn u give me some working sample...m new to this javascript...

Comment: Ok, I updated my code. But I'm afraid this `OBJECT` will work in IE only. And you need to search completely different way, how do that.

Comment: your code is not working in both IE and Firefox getting error in IE as document is not defined